# Django Querysets - Objects including entire set in ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model, `Respondent`, related to another model `Questionnaire` via a `ManyToMany` field named `finished`.

I have a set of four `Questionnaire` objects and would like to retrieve all `Respondent` objects that have a `finished` relationship with all four.

I would also like to retrieve the inverse: Any `Respondent` object which doesn't have a `finished` relationship with all four selected `Questionnaire` objects.

I've been looking through [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), and haven't found something that works for me. I am able to get all of the `Respondent` objects that match at least one of the `Questionnaire` objects with `Respondent.objects.filter(finished__in=questionnaire_queryset)` but that's as far as I've gotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could count the number of `finished` objects that are in the `questionnaire_queryset`, like:

from django.db.models import Count

```
Respondent.objects.filter(
    finished__in=questionnaire_queryset
).annotate(
    nfinish=Count('finished')
).filter(
    nfinish=len(questionnaire_queryset)
)
```

We make an assumption here that `questionnaire_queryset` does *not* contain any duplicates.

Comment: Got it. I had seen this around, but after playing with it it seemed that it was tallying all finished objects, not just those in the queryset. I will play with this some more, thank you!